# Netflix (native on chrome) has black screen, season video thumbnails are improperly aligned on the left, audio still plays

Tags: google-chrome, netflix

I recently ran into a problem where Netflix on Chrome would not work. Audio played correctly but the video did not play. The screen is black (in Chrome stable) or white (chrome beta). The thumbnail images, usually visible through the hover over menu bar, were positioned on the vertically left side of the screen.

What I'm on:

```
-Ubuntu 14.04, 64bit, kernel 3.14
-ASUS laptop, i7, Nvidia 870m, 16GB ram
```

What I checked:

```
-ensured pipelight is completely removed from my system
-ensured chrome and the DRM JS were up to date
-ensured HTML 5 is preferred in Netflix settings
```

What I've tried:

```
-the beta release
-deleting all history and cached information
-deleting the persistence in the local filesystem
-disabling hardware acceleration
-disabling WebGL
-Nvidia proprietary and open drivers
-disabled my second monitor
-restarted, shutdown + reboot
```

Answer (score 1):

The Solution (working on Chrome stable, not beta):

```
1. Navigate to "chrome://flags"
2. Find "Experiments" header (it's the first one at the time of this post)
3. Find "Disable accelerated 2D canvas"
4. Enable the option (disabling the acceleration)
5. Done
```

Side Note:
I don't know if its related, but I began experiencing these problems after an apt update/upgrade run I did on the day of this post.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I was upgraded from chrome 38 to 39. the newer version gave me the same issues you see. I went back to 38 and netflix works again.